# How do I create a new ul when crime name equals to 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Count Crimes

if the list of crimes is equal to 10 on 11 create a new list, This is the updated version of it sorry....

```
 <ul>  
  <% category.crimeheaders.each do |crimeheader| %> 
    <% crimeheader.crimes.each do |crime| %> 
      <li>
        <%= crime.id  %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= crime.name %>
      </li>

    <% end %>
  <% end
```

%>

How would i do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first you need to get the list of all crimes, regardless and not structured by crimeheader.

One way to do this is to add a relation to crimes at the category level, through the `crimeheaders` relation:

```
class Category
    has_many :crimeheaders
    has_many :crimes, through: :crimeheaders # this is what you add 
    ...
end
```

Once you have this, you can loop through all crimes in a category, in batches of 10.

```
<% category.crimes.each_slice(10) do | batch | %>

<ul>

  <% batch.each do |crime| %>

    <li><%= crime.name %></li>

  <% end %>

</ul>

<% end %>
```

That will get all the crimes for the category, then give you slices of 10 at a time to display in lists.

Now, if you want to get clever, you can actually retrieve from the db in batches of 10.
Probably not worth it, but here is the idea:

```
<% Crime.where(category_id: 123).find_in_batches( batch_size: 10 ) do | batch | %>

<ul>

  <% batch.each do |crime| %>

    <li><%= crime.name %></li>

  <% end %>

</ul>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey I updated the question check it out... i was using that as an example but i failed miserably in doing what you are doing!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do better.  Are you trying to do a list per crimeheader? Per category? Per every ten for a given crimeheader, for every ten regardless of crimeheader? You added categories and crimeheaders, but aren't explaining things.

Comment: Ahh im sorry,  for every ten regardless of crimeheader

Comment: ah - in that case, you need to get all crimes for the category, I'll update my answer for this.